# Javascript function for returning strings in an array that are longer than defined number

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to write a function that takes an array of strings and a number that returns the strings in an array that are a longer length than the defined number.

Below is the code that I have started with:

```
var words = ["Harold", "hen", "asdasda"];

var i = 5
words.sort(function filterLongWords(x , i){
    if (words[x].length > i){
        return words[x];
    }
    else {
        console.log("You have no words longer than the number " + i + ".");
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Good for you... what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do what you intend to using `Array.filter` and `Array.length`

```
var longWords = words.filter(function(str) { return str.length > i; });
if (longWords.length == 0) {
  console.log("You have no words longer than the number " + i + ".");
}
```